# Logs of Gnuplot for startupt?

Tags: macos, installation, crash, homebrew, gnuplot

I have now many times uninstalled and installed different gnuplots. 
However, now, the gnuplot with qt crashes in the startup if I simply run

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'data.dat'"
```

The crash occurs such that the qt window opens shortly after the command but crashes in about 0.01 second such that I can see only a blink of the window. 
My system is OSX Yosemite and I did the installations with brew.

I have uninstalled it many times and reinstalled but the problem persists. 
I have updated my system. 
My *.gnuplotrc* is empty.

**How can you get logs about the internals of gnuplot?** 
I want to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I  suppose that it is not really crashing but you're only experiencing a fast computer. Try to add the option `-persist`. Something like `gnuplot -e "plot 'data.dat'" -persist`. It's possible that you had somehow the persist option enabled in your previous installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before of all you need to be sure that `gnuplot` is crashing. To do it just run your command and after ask to the shell the exit code with `echo $?`

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'data.dat'"
echo $?
```

- If it returns `0` it means the execution finished without error.
  The `-persist` parameter can fix your problem.

```
gnuplot -persist -e "plot 'data.dat'"
```

If it returns a number different from `0` it means it crashed.
From this [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Gnuplot#Debugging) you can read some tips:

> For debugging a `gnuplot` file, it is often useful to:
>
> - Change the terminal to interactive (instead of outputting to a file), by commenting out set terminal and output lines.
> - Start `gnuplot` interactively, then load the file in question.
> - Put pause -1 (pause until carriage return) at the end of the file, then run it from the command line.
> - Alternatively, run `gnuplot` with the `-persist` command line switch, so `gnuplot` exits, but the window persists.
> - Make the file itself executable, by shebang (#!) notation (depends on exact path):
>     `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist`

I can add that you can  call `gnuplot` with dash as the last parameter to stay in the interactive regime when the script completes.

```
gnuplot filename.gp - `
```

Then you can start to divide your script until you find the error (or you can write in some points lines as `print "here I am #1"` ...`print "here I am #n"`, execute it and read the last *Here I Am #*).

Last note:

It exists a `debug terminal` of `gnuplot` that if enabled in your version can help in the debug procedure.  [From here](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/Term-Gnuplot-0.90380905/GnuplotTerminals.pod#debug) it's possible to read about it

> This terminal is provided to allow for the debugging of gnuplot. It is likely to be of use only for users who are modifying the source code